# Перебор многомерных массивов JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, foreach, for

Имеется многомерный массив:

```
let arr = [];
arr.push[ 1, 3, 'N6IG0UeNmNpk1NWvAAAC'];
arr.push[ 2, 20, 'IPWjginzUgBv3XNVAAAC'];
```

И так далее, значений 5.
1-ое значение, это ID.
При новом подключении пользователя нужно пройтись по этому массиву и если такого ID ещё не было, занести, например как:

```
let userId = data.userId;
arr.push[userId, 0, 'nzUgBv3XNG0UeNmNp'];
```

Перепробовал много вариантов и с `for` и с  `forEach`, но никак не могу придти к правильному решению.
Может кто уже решал подобную задачу, подскажет.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Задача непонятно

Comment: Только у вас опечатки в коде, правильно с круглыми скобками: `arr.push( 1, 3, 'N6IG0UeNmNpk1NWvAAAC');`

Comment: Или точнее так, если массив многомерный: `arr.push([ 1, 3, 'N6IG0UeNmNpk1NWvAAAC']);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, можно так:

```js
let arr = [];
arr.push([ 1, 3, 'N6IG0UeNmNpk1NWvAAAC']);
arr.push([ 2, 20, 'IPWjginzUgBv3XNVAAAC']);

let userId = 3;
if (!arr.find(([id]) => id === userId)) arr.push([userId, 0, 'nzUgBv3XNG0UeNmNp']);

userId = 2;
if (!arr.find(([id]) => id === userId)) arr.push([userId, 0, '...']);

console.log(arr);
```

Но если не хотите каждый раз проходить по всему массиву, лучше параллельно создавать структуру типа Object или Set с уже занесёнными идентификаторами, у этих структур проверка наличия элемента занимает меньше времени.

Comment: `или Set` - а лучше WeakSet, чтоб не заботиться об удалении при закрытии соединения